# Iterating through and removing from a value list of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

So I have abstracted a project I was working on to test how adding and removing keys and values from dictionaries that have a list as their value.  Essentially I have a dictionary that has its Key/Value pair be the channel name and a list of users in the channel.

I ended up figuring out how to append values particular keys creating new keys with intended values but removing intended values from dictionaries with value lists seems more difficult.

I'll quickly describe a few quick details about this design which again is simplified from the project for testing purposes and just time I guess.  The user is prompted to enter a name that is to be added or removed from a channel or list of channels.  The format is either JOIN/PART followed by a list of comma separated "channels".  It looks like JOIN #foo,#bar,#dog.  For testing the symbol is not actually necessary, and you may also join or leave 1 channel at a time.

My issue is in the part() function I'm having trouble actually finding a way to iterate through the channels to detect if a user is in a channel then removing them from that channel.

There is a list function also for testing purposes but very simply just prints the dictionary.

I also don't really have error checking for this due to the original using regex to make sure the commands are correct, so if you break away from the format described above it prolly will break things.

```
channels = {'#foo':['sean', 'john', 'tim'],
            '#bar':['sean', 'paul', 'tim'],
            '#cat':['paul', 'john', 'tim'],
            '#dog':['sam', 'john', 'tim']}

def part(name, channelNameList):
    for channelName in channelNameList:
        if channelName in channels:
            # if user is in the list remove them, else print user is not in list
            pass
        else:
            print("Channel {} does not exist")

def list():
    print(channels)

while True:
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    command = input("Enter command: ")
    
    if command == "list":
        list()
    else:
        removeCommand = command.split(" ", -1)
        params = removeCommand[1].split(",", -1)
        
        if removeCommand[0] == "PART":
            part(name, params)
```

Comment: What is `channelNameList` initialized to in your `part()` function?

Comment: [`list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Oh im sorry, that was an artifact from the an older attempt, ill change that right away for clarity @RedCricket

Comment: It was meant to be the same setup as the join() function calling the params being passed channelNameList just because that seemed more clear than params but I forgot to change the name on that function.

Comment: You don't need to use `any()` just to check if an item is in a list. Use `if user in channels[channelName]:`

Comment: @c2huc2hu I was aware of some of the lists but if i did something along the lines of channels[channelName].remove() wouldn't that be attempting to remove the entire list with a particular name.  I was trying to remove indices within the values which themselves are lists.  I might be overthinking it maybe, ill test this now.

Comment: @Barmar thanks ill change that, the any does work but it did looks like a bit much compared to your idea

Comment: You're overthinking it. `remove()` takes an argument telling it what element to remove, it doesn't remove the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `remove()` to remove an element from a list.

```
def part(name, channelNameList):
    for channelName in channelNameList:
        if channelName in channels:
            try:
                channels[channelName].remove(name)
            except ValueError:
                print("User {} is not in {}".format(user, channelName)
        else:
            print("Channel {} does not exist")
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, i was just realizing that i was overcomplicating this severely after someone had posted about remove.  I thought the remove would do something entirely different so I had disqualified it as an option a bit earlier.

Comment: I think you were confusing it with `del channels[channelName]`